# variable in textarea template code closing textarea tag 

Tags: html, textarea

I have in my control panel ( HTML template editor )

```
<?
$textarea = '<textarea>';
$textarea .= $template_code;
$textarea .= '</textarea>';
echo $textarea;
?>
```

The variable `$template_code` contains html, including `</textarea>`

```
for example -> $template_code = '</textarea> ......';
```

This means the variable will close my `textarea` and other code will be outside my real `textarea`!!

How i can avoid this?

Comment: So `$template_code` contains HTML? Do you want to show the HTML in the textarea? Then you probably have to escape it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `htmlentities` to escape the special characters.

```
echo '<textarea>'.htmlentities($template_code).'</textarea>';
```

Comment: Or better: `<textarea><?php echo htmlentities($template_code); ?></textarea>`.